# appium query- Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException

Tags: appium-android

I have tried running several times this code in my eclipse IDE but everytime this comes up with the below errors. I really do not know what is wrong and how I can fix this. Please could someone help. I have written the below code in my IDE.

```
File f = new File("src"); File fs = new File(f,"ApiDemos-debug.apk");
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Demo");
cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());
System.setProperty("webdriver.http.factory", "apache");
AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are using latest Appium server 1.9.1 and Java client 6.1.0.
2. Latest Android SDK and ADB is installed.
3. Uninstall Appium setting and unlock app from your device.
4. USB debugging is enabled on the device.
5. Your desired capabilities should be minimum as follows:

Sample desired capabilities:

```
final DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.android ();
caps.setCapability (CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
caps.setCapability (MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "7.0");
caps.setCapability (MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "your device name");
caps.setCapability (MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/your/app/path/app.apk");
AndroidDriver <AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver <> (new URL ("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
```